# Joining, CASE and operations

Tags: sql, join, case

How would I write this formula in SQL?

```
IF ((TableA.Col1-TableA.Col2-TableA.Col3)-(TableB.Col1*TableB.Col2))<(TableB.Col1*0.10) 
THEN TableA.Col4-30, 
ELSE TableA.Col4
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON (TableA.Col1-TableA.Col2-TableA.Col3)-(TableB.Col1*TableB.Col2)<(TableB.Col1*0.1‌​0)
```

and then I get lost.

I want to decrease TableA.Col4 by 30 (so if TableA.Col4 is 50, then the result would be 20).

Comment: But you are using something resembling ANSI SQL? What have you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried using this:

Comment: Are you actually trying to decrease `TableA.Col4` by 30, or select that smaller value?  (`UPDATE` vs `SELECT CASE`)

Comment: SELECT FROM TableA INNER JOINE TableB ON (TableA.Col1-TableA.Col2-TableA.Col3)-(TableB.Col1*TableB.Col2)<(TableB.Col1*0.10)      ---and then I get lost

Comment: I want to decrease TableA.Col4 by 30 (so if TableA.Col4 is 50, then the result would be 20)

Comment: `INNER JOINE TableB ` -->> `INNER JOIN TableB `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're missing the relationship between tableA and tableB. If there is some sort of one-to-one primary key, use that for 'pk' in the query below

```
SELECT 
case
when (TableA.Col1-TableA.Col2-TableA.Col3)-(TableB.Col1*TableB.Col2)<(TableB.Col1*0.1‌​0) 
then TableA.Col4-30 
else TableA.Col4 
end
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableA.pk=TableB.pk
```

Comment: does it make a different is this statement has to be inputted in one continuous line? In other words, I do not have the option to create different statements on different lines. Here is what it would look like for me.....SELECT CASE WHEN (TableA.Col1-TableA.Col2-TableA.Col3)-(TableB.Col1*TableB.Col2)<(TableB.Col1*0.10) THEN TableA.Col4-30 ELSE TableA.Col4 END FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.Acctno=TableB.Acctno

Comment: I GOT IT! THANK YOU SO MUCH Andreas.